# What is java:comp/env scope rules?

Tags: java

I understand that `java:comp/env` is the node in the JNDI tree where you can find properties for the current Java EE component (a webapp, or an EJB), and also I know that each EJB has its own component environment ,also there is `java:global` and `java:app` and a `java:module` depending on that I have some questions

1. when I use `Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");` to get initContext what Context exactly I get (global,app,module,webApp or EJB Context)?
2. Is there is certain rules applied for searching different scopes?
3. Let's say I have web application with many EJBs,does this means that I have many Initial Contexts (one for webApp and one for each EJB) or all of these resources are somehow collected under one context `java:comp/env`?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. when I use Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env"); to get initContext what Context exactly I get (global,app,module,webApp or EJB Context)?

Quoting from TomEE documentation http://tomee.apache.org/lookup-of-other-ejbs-example.html

> In a webapp, the java:comp/env namespace is shared by all servlets.
>   This is essentially equivalent to the java:module namespace in Java EE
>   6. Understand there is a conflict in definition here and that for EJBs, java:comp is scoped at the component (the EJB itself) not the
>   module as with webapps.

2. Is there is certain rules applied for searching different scopes?

Quoting from JavaEE 6 Tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html

> The java:global JNDI namespace is the portable way of finding remote
>   enterprise beans using JNDI lookups. The java:module namespace is used
>   to look up local enterprise beans within the same module.  The
>   java:app namespace is used to look up local enterprise beans packaged
>   within the same application. That is, the enterprise bean is packaged
>   within an EAR file containing multiple Java EE modules.

3. Let's say I have web application with many EJBs,does this means that I have many Initial Contexts (one for webApp and one for each EJB) or all of these resources are somehow collected under one context java:comp/env?

> Based on above links, you will have not have many contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 3 on the scope of `java:comp/env` in presence of EJBs.

Traditionally (before JEE 6) `java:comp/env` was module level for `war` modules and EJB level for EJBs in `jar` modules.
In that model, one has to define environment entries (via `resource-ref` and `env-entry` in `ejb-jar.xml`, or for resource-refs since JEE5 one could use `@Resource` at the class level) for every single EJB.

```
<ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>B1</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>p1.B1</ejb-class> <!-- ejb-class should be skipped if bean is already defined via annotation -->
      <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>entry1</env-entry-name>        
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>value1</env-entry-value
      </env-entry>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Since JEE 6, one can deploy EJBs as part of `war` module. Whether `war` module is deployed directly or is part or `ear` module, it has a single `java:comp/env` namespace shared between all servlets, EJBs and any other code within that module. One can define environment entries in `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
  <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>entry1</env-entry-name>        
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>value1</env-entry-value
  </env-entry>
</web-app>
```

In this `war` based model, one could still have `ejb-jar.xml` to configure other aspects of EJBs, but `env-entry` for a given bean in `ejb-jar.xml` would end up injecting the environment value for all other beans in the `war`.

So, I would always use `war` archives for everything (possibly packaged in `ear`).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. When I use Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env"); to get initContext what Context exactly I get (global,app,module,webApp or EJB Context)?

You get the one you asked for, the one you correctly described as 'the current Java EE component (a webapp, or an EJB)'.

> 2. Is there is certain rules applied for searching different scopes?

You search within the scope you specify. I don't know what else your question could mean.

> 3. Let's say I have web application with many EJBs, does this means that I have many Initial Contexts (one for webApp and one for each EJB) or all of these resources are somehow collected under one context java:comp/env?

The question doesn't make sense. You have as many `InitialContexts` as you create. They are objects. *What they refer to* depends on what you lookup *within* that `InitialContext`. If you keep looking up `"the current Java EE component (a webapp, or an EJB)"`, you will keep getting exactly that. All 'these resources' are 'collected' under their own names respectively, *within* `java:comp/env`.

Comment: Thanks EJP.The first and the third questions, i means is there is IntialContext for the webApp and anther one for the EJB components and others which i don't know about.  The second question i know about four nodes 'java:comp/env' 'java:global' 'java:app' 'java:module' at which order JNDI will look up for resource?

Answer (score 0):

As far of my knowledge by default the scope will be Global